# Music during Sefiras HaOmer

Tags: halacha, music, sefirat-ha-omer

What is the halachic definition of "music"?

I am unsure that such a thing exists, but if it does, I would like to know.

EDIT: I am aware that we are only prohibited from listening to instrumental music. I want to know what the "music" part means.

EDIT2: This was flagged as a "duplicate," and it does appear related to the the question from 2012 linked to the flag, but the question was certainly not answered there.

I would like a halachic definition of "music" - if this does not exist, do let me know.

Comment: Whether it was answered or not doesn't mean it isn't the same question.

Comment: Can you indicate why you are "aware" that instrumental music is the only problem?